# Не отображается кирилица в консоли

Tags: java, intellij-idea, кодировка, консоль

У меня не читабельный вывод русских символов в консоли после запуска тестов

Что было попробовано:

1. Изменить кодировку в File->Settings>Editor->File Encodings
   Global Encoding  и Project Encoding выбрал  (перед этим проверил что везде в системе по умолчанию русский язык, то есть в Региональных настройках)  и Default Encoding for properties files поставил UTF-8
2. Внизу проекта в нижнем правом углу проверил UTF-8
3. Проверил в chcp было 866 в cmd
4. В файлах Idea IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.8\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions и idea64.exe.vmoptions, также доступные через Help->Edit Custom VM Options..., я добавил строку -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8.
5. Во всех pom.xml прописал кодировку

   ```
   <encoding.type>UTF-8</encoding.type>

   <project.build.sourceEncoding>${encoding.type}</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${encoding.type</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
   <file.encoding>${encoding.type}</file.encoding>
   ```
6. А так же добавлял параметр `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` в строке запуска конфигурации (Edit configurations) `clean test -pl tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd -fae -P bdd-tests,sbpegas-mon-qa -DfailIfNoTests=false **-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8** -Dcucumber.options.tags=@algIvan`

При том если я просто создаю класс и печатаю русские символы всё ок.

Help

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\kakty\Desktop\JavaDela\cc-tr2mongarantee1234 -Dmaven.home=B:\Mav\apache-maven-3.5.2 -Dclassworlds.conf=B:\Mav\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\m2.conf "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.8\lib\idea_rt.jar=51889:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.8\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath B:\Mav\apache-maven-3.5.2\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2018.2.8 -Dmaven.repo.local=C:\Users\kakty\.m2\repository clean test -pl tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd -fae -P bdd-tests,sbpegas-mon-qa -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dcucumber.options.tags=@ivan1
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CC - TR2MONGARANTY - Testing - BDD CURRENT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\kakty\Desktop\JavaDela\cc-tr2mongarantee1234\tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 36 source files to C:\Users\kakty\Desktop\JavaDela\cc-tr2mongarantee1234\tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd\target\classes
[WARNING] /C:/Users/kakty/Desktop/JavaDela/cc-tr2mongarantee1234/tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd/src/main/java/ru.sberbank.pegas.at.bdd/stepdefs/UtilSteps.java:[149,17] withTimeout(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) in org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait has been deprecated
[WARNING] /C:/Users/kakty/Desktop/JavaDela/cc-tr2mongarantee1234/tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd/src/main/java/ru.sberbank.pegas.at.bdd/stepdefs/UtilSteps.java:[152,17] pollingEvery(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) in org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait has been deprecated
[WARNING] /C:/Users/kakty/Desktop/JavaDela/cc-tr2mongarantee1234/tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd/src/main/java/ru.sberbank.pegas.at.bdd/stepdefs/UtilSteps.java:[186,17] withTimeout(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) in org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait has been deprecated
[WARNING] /C:/Users/kakty/Desktop/JavaDela/cc-tr2mongarantee1234/tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd/src/main/java/ru.sberbank.pegas.at.bdd/stepdefs/UtilSteps.java:[189,17] pollingEvery(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) in org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait has been deprecated
[WARNING] /C:/Users/kakty/Desktop/JavaDela/cc-tr2mongarantee1234/tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd/src/main/java/ru.sberbank.pegas.at.bdd/stepdefs/UtilSteps.java:[406,17] withTimeout(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) in org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait has been deprecated
[WARNING] /C:/Users/kakty/Desktop/JavaDela/cc-tr2mongarantee1234/tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd/src/main/java/ru.sberbank.pegas.at.bdd/stepdefs/UtilSteps.java:[409,17] pollingEvery(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) in org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait has been deprecated
[WARNING] /C:/Users/kakty/Desktop/JavaDela/cc-tr2mongarantee1234/tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd/src/main/java/ru.sberbank.pegas.at.bdd/stepdefs/UtilSteps.java:[426,17] withTimeout(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) in org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait has been deprecated
[WARNING] /C:/Users/kakty/Desktop/JavaDela/cc-tr2mongarantee1234/tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd/src/main/java/ru.sberbank.pegas.at.bdd/stepdefs/UtilSteps.java:[429,17] pollingEvery(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) in org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait has been deprecated
[WARNING] /C:/Users/kakty/Desktop/JavaDela/cc-tr2mongarantee1234/tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd/src/main/java/ru.sberbank.pegas.at.bdd/stepdefs/IntegrationSteps.java:[103,17] withTimeout(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) in org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait has been deprecated
[WARNING] /C:/Users/kakty/Desktop/JavaDela/cc-tr2mongarantee1234/tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd/src/main/java/ru.sberbank.pegas.at.bdd/stepdefs/IntegrationSteps.java:[106,17] pollingEvery(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) in org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait has been deprecated
[INFO] /C:/Users/kakty/Desktop/JavaDela/cc-tr2mongarantee1234/tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd/src/main/java/ru.sberbank.pegas.at.bdd/stepdefs/IntegrationSteps.java: C:\Users\kakty\Desktop\JavaDela\cc-tr2mongarantee1234\tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd\src\main\java\ru.sberbank.pegas.at.bdd\stepdefs\IntegrationSteps.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/Users/kakty/Desktop/JavaDela/cc-tr2mongarantee1234/tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd/src/main/java/ru.sberbank.pegas.at.bdd/stepdefs/IntegrationSteps.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 189 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\kakty\Desktop\JavaDela\cc-tr2mongarantee1234\tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ tr2mongaranty-component-test-bdd ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
INFO Reflections took 219 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 2 keys and 39 values 
WARNING: Found tags option '~@Ignore'. Support for '~@tag' will be removed from the next release of Cucumber-JVM. Please use 'not @tag' instead.
INFO @algIvan

INFO �㭪樮���: �஢�ઠ �����⬮�

INFO 

INFO   @algIvan @ivan1

INFO   �業�਩: �஢�ઠ ���祭�� TRUE �����⬮�                                                                                                                                                       # features/simpleDeals+/GetLegalClientProfileAlgo/mon/Ivan1.feature:6

[INFO] Running �஢�ઠ �����⬮�
INFO     * ������:"�����" "���ਧ��� �� ��� ��� �������" "�業�਩: ���ਧ��� �� ��� ��� �������"                                                                                                    # UtilSteps.startImport(String,String,String)

INFO     ���� ⥪�騩 ���짮��⥫� "admin"                                                                                                                                                               # UtilSteps.setCurrentUser(String)

INFO     � �⪫�砥��� ��⨥ �ਭ�� ����� 蠣���                                                                                                                                                     # UtilSteps.switchGettingScreenshot(String)

INFO ���樠������ ���-�ࠩ��� � ������ 92120749-ed84-42be-94c4-7ffbdf84b3fb
INFO Attempt #1 to start web driver
```

И дальше стартует веб драйвер и идёт процесс прогона теста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Закрыть Intellij IDEA
2. Добавить в файлы idea.exe.vmoptions и idea64.exe.vmoptions строку `-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8`
3. Запустить Intellij IDEA

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло

Comment: @ule попробуйте добавить строки `-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8` и `--Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` в файл idea64.exe.vmoptions по пути C:\Users\USER_NAME\.IntelliJIdea....\config\idea64.exe.vmoptions

Comment: Когда я открыл C:\Users\USER_NAME\.IntelliJIdea....\config\idea64.exe.vmoptions, там уже были строчки -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8 и -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
в комментарии выше  вы написали с двумя тире --Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, но я предположил что это просто опечатка, ибо с двумя тире у меня вообще идея не стала стартовать

Comment: @ule да, 2 тире это опечатка

Comment: Тогда там уже были эти строчки, я их проверил и всё

Comment: @ule у вас какая винда стоит?

Comment: -Windows 10 Pro

Comment: @ule попробуйте: 1) установить значение 866 для параметра OEMCP866 по пути \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage 2) в параметры регионального стандарта > дополнительно > изменить язык системы - убрать галочку с параметра "Бета-версия: Использовать Юникод (UTF-8) для поддержки языка во всем мире 3) Сохранить и перезагрузить.

Comment: Я читал, что нужно убрать галочку с параметра "Бета-версия: Использовать Юникод (UTF-8) для поддержки языка во всем мире , но у меня она изначально была убрана, но пару минут назад чисто ради эксперимента я её решил поставить и после перезагрузки у меня стала отображаться кириллица нормально.
Большое спасибо за помощь в решении вопроса!

Comment: @ule пожалуйста, рад, что всё получилось

Comment: Выше я допустил опечатку в имени параметра: нужно OEMCP, а не OEMCP866

Answer (score 3):

При решение этого вопроса пришлось испробовать много разных методов найденных на различных ресурсах решил их объединить вместе здесь.

1. Изменить кодировку в File->Settings>Editor->File Encodings Global Encoding и Project Encoding выбрал (перед этим проверил что везде в системе по умолчанию русский язык, то есть в Региональных настройках) и Default Encoding for properties files поставил UTF-8

   Примечание: Касательно галочки в поле Default Encoding for properties files UTF-8 на многих ресурсах пишут, что эту галочку нужно убрать, но мне помогло именно поставить её.
2. Внизу проекта в нижнем правом углу проверить UTF-8
3. Проверить в cmd командой chcp должно быть 866

   Примечание: Если это не так
   Установить значение 866 для параметра OEMCP по пути \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage
4. В файлах `Idea IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.8\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions` и `idea64.exe.vmoptions`, также доступные через `Help->Edit Custom VM Options...`,  добавить строку `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` и `-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8`.
5. Во всех pom.xml прописал кодировку

   ```
   <encoding.type>UTF-8</encoding.type>

   <project.build.sourceEncoding>${encoding.type}</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${encoding.type</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
   <file.encoding>${encoding.type}</file.encoding>
   ```

   Примечание: Не обязательный пункт
6. Добавить параметр `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` в строке запуска конфигурации (Edit configurations) `clean test “Ваши параметры конфигурации” -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
7. Добавить строки `-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8` и `--Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` в файл `idea64.exe.vmoptions` по пути `C:\Users\USER_NAME\.IntelliJIdea....\config\idea64.exe.vmoptions`

Примечание: Отличается от пункта №4

Answer (score 3):

*Актуально на 31.03.2022 для версии Intellij idea 2021.3*

Приветствую, мне помогла смена кодировки не на **UTF-8**, а на кодировку которая стоит в системе по умолчанию(в моём случае это **windows-1251**). Если вы используете другую операционную систему, то у вас кодировка может отличаться. Чтобы всё заработало, поменяйте значение в параметрах **"Global encoding:"** и **"Project encoding:"** на **"Default"** (параметры располагаются в Intellij idea по пути **File->Settings->Editor->File encodings**).

Answer (score 2):

File - Settings - Editor - Console - Default Encoding - UTF-8